# Can I merge two, or more, separate Titanium backups

Tags: sms, backup, titanium-backup

In this case I'm looking to restore SMS messages from Titanium.

I have made a backup of all SMS. Then I started on a new ROM without restoring SMS. I then made a new backup of the current SMS.

Is it possible to combine those two separate backups so that when I restore I will get my SMS from both backups?

As I understand, if I restore one backup, then I restore another backup it will not combine them but rather write one over the other.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is more like a manual job, but can be done.

With [Titanium Backup PRO/Donate version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro), you have this feature ([compare versions here](http://www.titaniumtrack.com/titanium-backup.html)):

> Backup/restore SMS, MMS, call log, bookmarks and Wi-Fi networks in the portable XML format!

You can combine both SMS backups into a single XML file format and restore it to your phone all in one. Afterwards, perform a backup like you usually do, to have it all together.

**Ps:** Will probably require you to go back and forward, but here's a guide:

1. Backup to XML the existent SMS on your device;
2. Restore the old SMS to the device;
3. backup the old SMS to XML;
4. Edit both XML files to merge them;
5. Restore all back to your device.

You can refer to [Titanium Backup website](http://www.titaniumtrack.com/) to collect more information or to request support from the developers.