# How can I import new SMS into my phone without wiping the current SMS?

Tags: sms, backup

Situation:  Old phone broke, got a new phone.  Used new phone for a week and accumulated a fair amount of SMS (on a fresh new phone)

Decided to finally restore from previous phone backup that was a month old.  Restoring from backup wiped all the new SMS I have made.

Luckily I have made a backup of the New SMS before they were wiped by the old backup.

But now I want to import the new SMS (located in the new backup) into my phone *without* wiping the old SMS.

**How can I do so?**

I used MyBackup Pro to do the backup/restore.  It does not seem to have an option of "Merge" ...

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2232/1465)?  I'm not sure if that suggestion requires manual editing or not.  If you redid those backups with Titanium Backup then [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/28005/1465) would be an option.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11089277/4720957) and an SQL Manager I downloaded from the Internet.

Essentially, using my mad SQL skills, I browsed into *sms* table, did an *UPDATE* on *_id* field as per table structure of rerware Backup Pro to avoid primary key collisions, then did the merges per the linked answer. I later uploaded the database back into my phone.

I'm doing a restore now.  If I don't come back complaining, it means it worked!

yep it worked.  I think I missed *some* SMS from a single person, but that was not related to the above machinations.