# Is there a way to combine SMS from different Android versions

Tags: sms, backup, restore

I'm looking for a proper way which will allow to combine SMS from two different devices with different Android versions.
I took a look into this [solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28005) but it doesn't explain the step "4. Edit both XML files to merge them;" - how to do it?

Comment: Please provide an example of the code in XML 1 and 2 ... You may need to just copy and paste an entire section or edit manually the details .... for example if XML 1 has number ordering from message 1 to say 99... then merging the second file ( manually copying and pasting ) is a headache because you'll end up with two messages in the first position, meaning you need to edit the first message in XML 2 to say 99+1 ( 100 ) and then the second becomes 101 etc..